# Second y scale with ggplot package

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'd like to change the ticks of the second y scale with start in `z[1]` and end in `z[17]`. Below I presented a MWE with the dataset and the `ggplot` code

```
             x1           x2           x3           x4         y           z
       59.72297     58.92972     61.34541     57.20393   (6.5,7]   0.0000000
       59.03954     58.24224     60.67139     56.50889   (7,7.5]  -0.6834285
       58.35261     57.55155     59.99327     55.81127   (7.5,8]  -1.3703668
       57.66241     56.85789     59.31130     55.11136   (8,8.5]  -2.0605641
       56.96921     56.16153     58.62573     54.40941   (8.5,9]  -2.7537648
       56.27326     55.46274     57.93679     53.70571   (9,9.5]  -3.4497086
       55.57484     54.76178     57.24476     53.00053  (9.5,10]  -4.1481307
       54.87421     54.05892     56.54987     52.29415 (10,10.5]  -4.8487626
       54.17164     53.35445     55.85240     51.58685 (10.5,11]  -5.5513324
       53.46741     52.64863     55.15261     50.87892 (11,11.5]  -6.2555650
       52.76179     51.94176     54.45078     50.17063 (11.5,12]  -6.9611827
       52.05507     51.23411     53.74717     49.46227 (12,12.5]  -7.6679055
       51.34752     50.52596     53.04207     48.75413 (12.5,13]  -8.3754518
       50.63943     49.81760     52.33575     48.04649 (13,13.5]  -9.0835386
       49.93109     49.10932     51.62850     47.33963 (13.5,14]  -9.7918820
       49.22277     48.40139     50.92059     46.63384 (14,14.5] -10.5001978
       48.51477     47.69410     50.21232     45.92939 (14.5,15] -11.2082017

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = y, y = x1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue")
p + geom_line(data = df, mapping = aes(x = y, y = x1 + z, group = 1), size = 2, color = 'red') + 
scale_y_continuous(name = "Axis 1", sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~. -59.72, name = "Axis 2"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = y, y = x1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue")
p +
  geom_line(data = df, mapping = aes(x = y, y = x1 + z, group = 1), size = 2, color = 'red') + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Axis 1",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ approx(range(.), range(df$z), xout=.)$y,
                                         name = "Axis 2"))
```

[image: ggplot2 plot]

(I'm not totally thrilled with reaching out to `df` from inside the `trans`formation, but it seems harmless enough in this context.)

I **do** think this is breaching the interpretation of the original data. That is, `x1` spans from 48.5 to 59.7 and `z` from -11.2 to 0, but the plot states that `z`'s range is associated with `x1`'s span from 0 to 59.7, so the slope of the relationship is mis-stated. While I assume that this data is just sample data for the sake of this question, I wonder if there's room for concern about mis-representation of value comparisons.